# The way to "reinit" repository

Tags: git

I've made kind of a big refactoring in my project: I renamed files, removed, added... Besides, I added some folders in .gitignore. However, I've already made a commit to a remote repository before refactoring.

Is there any to make git "reinit" for my repository? If there is not, what should I do?

**Update**:

I have deleted the folder .git and now I have an error of

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') hint: before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I don't want to merge the local changes with the remote repo, I just want to push there, meaning completely replace the remote repository with the local one.

Comment: Do you want to have a clean history by "reinit"?  Why don't you simply move forward and commit the new changes?

Comment: @Mingyu, I've made only one commit, so having a clean repository is a good idea.

Comment: What's the nature of the remote repo?  If it doesn't have any active clones, just replace it.

Comment: I have deleted the folder .git and now I have an error of `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.` I don't want to merge the local changes with the remote repo, I just want to push there or remote the remote repo and after that push there.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't delete and re-create your remote repo.

Comment: @tadman, I deleted ".git" folder and reinit the repo.

Comment: Note that tadman said _remote_ repo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you have deleted the `.git` folder (not a great idea), you can create a new clone of the repo and move your stuff to that, and continue there. Something like this

```
cd ..
git clone <remote-repo-url> new-repo
rm -rf new-repo/*                          // this will not remove new-repo/.git
cp -f <original-local-repo> new-repo
cd new-repo
```

Then continue as below.

Note that it is better if you can restore the `.git` folder. Creating a new repo will loose all local repo information you had in the original local repo, like local branches that were never pushed.

**END UPDATE**

You could

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git add -A .
git commit -m "rewriting history"
git push --force origin master
```

This will back up to the previous commit (while preserving the working tree and index), commit your changes, and then force push that rewritten history to the remote.

`push --force` is dangerous stuff. It will disturb others who have already pulled, and is considered very rude, but if no one else have started work on it, that is not a problem.

This is what is happening:

```
--- A -- B  master

    ^
    |     
    origin/master

git push

--- A -- B master, origin/master

git reset HEAD^
git commit -am "rewriting"

--- A -- B origin/master
     \
      \
       B' master

git push --force

--- A -- B
     \
      \
       B' master, origin/master
```

Comment: Does that work?  I thought git was designed not to accept remote commits that delete history. Or is that what --force does?

Comment: You can rewrite history all day, but the hash of your commits will change. You can't alter the contents of a commit, but you can amend it, creating a new commit of sorts, and you can redefine what your `master` points to.

Answer (score 12):

At first, remove your initial repository by this code

```
rm -rf .git
```

Then create a new repository and puts the given code which we use for the initial git repository. I am sure it will work without any error..!!!

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
```

Comment: How does git reinit remote repo?

Answer (score 9):

Here are steps to re-init repository.

**Scenario:** I have deleted a locally project folder that I have made git init previously. After that, I would like to update to the existing git repository with a new folder of same project. Then I solved it by following procedure.

**Procedure**

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -am "re-init"
git remote add origin https://github.com/{yourgit}/{yourproject}.git
git push --force origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

The lazy way is to just add all the new files and changes, and deletions:

```
git add -A .
```

So long as you don't have any conflicts, this should merge in fine.

Comment: But I don't want to delete these files from a project. Well, I want some of them to be deleted permanently (from repo and a disk), but for the rest of them  I only want them not to be in git index (to make git doesn't see them -- for those that in .gitignore). Do I have to remove all them manually by "git rm ..."?

Comment: You can always move these files out of your project temporarily, commit the "deletions", then move them back after where they'll be ignored from that point forward. Once moved, `git add -A .` will stage these deletions. After the commit, if your `.gitignore` is set up right, moving them back will have no effect on your repo.

Comment: git rm doesn't actually remove anything.  "Removed" files no longer show up in the current version but are still in historical versions. All prior versions are still in the .git directory.

Comment: If you really want to start over, which is kind of cheating, just delete the `.git` directory and `git init` again. You'll need to trash your remote repo and start over there, too, for them to be in sync. I think this defeats the purpose of revision control, though, and should be a last resort.

Comment: @Paul `git rm` will remove them from the filesystem, though, which means to keep using them you'll have to restore them to get back to where you would've been if they were only ignored in the first place.

Comment: @tadman Right.  For example if the file "code" is absent but was last in commit fa876... you would need to "git checkout fa876 code"

Comment: @Paul It's always been easier to simply move them aside, commit the changed state, and move them back than to go about re checking out so many different files.

Comment: I have no idea what you're using for hosting. If it's something like GitHub, delete and re-make it. Remember, you will lose all your history at this point.