# How can I re-init my git repo?

Tags: git

I've been doing some beginning work on a repo and I don't need the history.

I want to start from ground zero w/ no history?

Can I simply delete the `.git` folder and run `git init` again.

But how will this effect my remote repos?

Comment: You can do this, and it will not affect your remote repos at all (you'd have to delete those seperately if that is what you want).

Comment: delete on local, than checkout the repo again ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The way to "reinit" repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357369/the-way-to-reinit-repository)

Comment: @Thilo - exactly just remove the .git directory, run git init, remove all your remote repos and push again.

Comment: what is the deal with always making new questions dups - dooops

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
cd "$PWD/`git rev-parse --show-cdup`" #go to the project's root
rm -rf .git
```

And then:

```
git init .
#...
```

As for your remote repos, you'll need to `git push --force` into them (or push to a new, completely separate branch).

Comment: no you don't, i have one bare repo, I just deleted it, and recreated, very simple.

Comment: @cadegalt if you want to revert the history remotely as well, yes, you'll need to force push.

Comment: `cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup)` followed by `rm .\.git\ -Recurse -Force` is the Powershell equivalent.