# How to forbid atom to watch all changes stated in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have added framework and modules files into my project. I also wrote `.gitignore` to avoid uploading the changes but Atom watch all changes with project and added approximately 8000 files of framework as those that  are ready to pushed. My .gitignore already contains:
{!/folder_of_modules_i_wish_to_hide} What will you suggest?

Comment: share your .gitignore and make sure you have done git init the directory consisting .gitignore

Comment: https://github.com/Dignity1988/raven/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: It is gitignore node template but local is the same. I am trying to pull it in hope that atom will think it wrong to count node_modules as folder to push.

Comment: It seems that the .npm files have already been added to the version control. You need to remove it first, before it can be ignored. This can be done using git rm

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore they are not added as they are not stated with ! *sign but thnx for the command. I am getting error in puling .gitignore to the master branch because assume that it will be accepted right after pulling.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357369/the-way-to-reinit-repository - found that it is enoghtto reinit reprository : git init -> git add -A git commit -am "re-init" git remote add origin https://github.com/{yourgit}/{yourproject}.git

Comment: Thnx for the attention and assistance, Kasra.

Comment: The `!` prefix negates the pattern. Try removing that. More info at [man gitignore](https://gitirc.eu/gitignore.html).

Comment: Already solved by reinitializing the git as no matter what kind of pattern will be inserted ATOM refuse to "eat" .gitignore, but reinitinalizing it solved the issue. The topic can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

> solved by reinitializing the git as no matter what kind of pattern will be inserted ATOM refuse to "eat" .gitignore, but reinitinalizing it solved the issue.

That is one way.

The other way was `git rm --cached -- folder_of_modules_i_wish_to_hide/**`

That would have removed everything (while keeping the content on the disk): your `.gitignore` would have then worked.

Comment: There is also solution with removing completely from git project folder with force flag when caching not working..